# Operating with multiple datagridview

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I have two individual datagidview with data, DGV1 and DGV2. Now I want to make a 3rd datagrid DGV3, copy over the columns "LIST", "Theta" and "Phi", but for my last column in DGV3 ("Ampl (dB)"), I have to add the values in DGV1 and DGV2 and make it as a input to DGV Total. Assuming i there is two full datagridview, how can I handle my problem? Any help is strongly apricheded. the data comes from two individual Arduinos. The population of DGV1 and DGV2 happens in two EventHanldlers.

```
delegate void dataToGrid3(int deg, int de2, double ampl_Total, int seq);
private void adddataToGrid3(int deg, int deg2, double ampl_Total, int seq)
    {
        int row = 0;
        dataGridView3.Rows.Add();
        row = dataGridView3.Rows.Count - 2;
        dataGridView3["LIST3", row].Value = seq;
        dataGridView3["Theta3", row].Value = deg;
        dataGridView3["Phi3", row].Value = deg2;
        dataGridView3["Ampl_dB3", row].Value = ampl_Total;
    }
```

Trying to do use button to populate DGV Total:

```
private void DGV_Total_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < runCounter; i++)
        {

        }
    }
```

[image: How in looks]

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all `DataGridViewRows` from the first `DataGridView` DGV1. There you copy 'List' 'Theta' and 'Phi' from DGV1 directly in the third `DataGridView` DGV3. With using your row index you can get the value of each "Ampl (dB)" from both `DataGridViews` and sum them.

```
private void DGV_Total_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGV3.Rows.Clear();
    int yourColumnIndex = 3;    // column index from "Ampl (dB)"
    double total = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DGV1.Rows)
    {
        total = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[yourColumnIndex].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(DGV2.Rows[row.Index].Cells[yourColumnIndex].Value);
        adddataToGrid3(row.Cells[1].Value, row.Cells[2].Value, total, row.Cells[0].Value);
    }
}
```

You can also add the data directly in the `foreach` loop, which would look like this:

```
private void DGV_Total_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DGV3.Rows.Clear();
    int yourColumnIndex = 3;    // column index from "Ampl (dB)"
    double total = 0;           
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DGV1.Rows)
    {
        total = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[yourColumnIndex].Value) + Convert.ToDouble(DGV2.Rows[row.Index].Cells[yourColumnIndex].Value);
        DGV3.Rows.Add(new object[] { row.Cells[0].Value,    //copy List
                                     row.Cells[1].Value,    //copy Theta
                                     row.Cells[2].Value,    //copy Phi
                                     total });              //add total "Ampl (dB)"
    }
}
```